# when real FREE the memory in STL

Tags: c++, stl

the STL's allocator use the memory pool tech, and it only add the memory needed deallocate into the free list, like this:

```
static void deallocate(void* __p, size_t __n)
{
    if (__n > (size_t) _MAX_BYTES)
    malloc_alloc::deallocate(__p, __n);
    else {
        _Obj* __STL_VOLATILE*  __my_free_list = _S_free_list + _S_freelist_index(__n);
        _Obj* __q = (_Obj*)__p;
        __q -> _M_free_list_link = *__my_free_list;
        *__my_free_list = __q;
    }
}
```

I want to know, when really FREE the free list?

Comment: Which implementation are you using, and what do you mean by "really free"?

Comment: It depends: * On STL implementation, * On OS, * On machine architecture. I believe it returns block of memory when there are no used memory in that block. So if OS gave you a 4 mb page, and there is at least one byte in use it will not be freed as you cannot return back part of page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that the STL uses memory pools (although it is common).

It will depend on the implementation (compiler, library, version, OS, machine architecture, phase of the moon).  A common answer is that memory allocated with new will only be returned to the operating system at program exit.

Comment: Actually, memory allocated with new and _small size_ is generally only returned to the operating system at program exit. Memory allocated with _large size_ (what those terms mean is rather platform-dependent) is returned upon delete.

Comment: Yes, that's another common approach.